# Spring Batch Scheduling

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, scheduled-tasks, schedule, job-scheduling

I am new to Spring batch. I have to create batch jobs and these jobs should be scheduled as per the below parameters. Kindly help me in setting up the coding for the below batch job scheduling parameters mentioned. That would be a very kind help to me.

1. Job ID/ Job Description [we can even give a view of its underlying steps]
2. Frequency of trigger [In Cycles, daily once, Minutes, Hourly, specific
   defined time, weekly,        fortnightly, monthly, quarterly] with its
   respective threshold values e.g. day/time etc.
3. Retry attempts post dependency condition not met.
4. Retry attempts post exceptions.
5. Monitoring Alert communication hierarchy emails/ phone numbers [Level-1,
   Level-2, etc.]
6. Monitoring Alert communication email/ SMS template.
7. Exceptions Alert communication hierarchy emails/ phone numbers [Level-1,
   Level-2, etc.]
8. Exceptions Alert communication email/ SMS template

Comment: Spring Batch isn't for scheduling and has nothing to do with scheduling. You can use regular spring `@Scheduled` for scheduling. Also I feel like you copied some word document into this and the question is hardly readable.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I make it readable.

Comment: That question is way too broad. It isn't about scheduling but also monitoring/observing etc. which is too broad.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But, is there anyway any suggestions or any other help to reach there?

Comment: As stated the question is to broad you have multiple questions and those seem to come from some requirement document. Feels like you want us to do your job for you. Scheduling is easily done with `@Scheduled` for the rest you will need to either write different questions or do better research.

Comment: Yeah, it's true that the question is broad. This is actually a requirement for me to do. I have given a good time on it. But did not succeed 100%. I didn't want my job done by you guys. What I wanted was only the overview whether I am heading in the right direction and nothing else.